# Is there a way to set the launchUrl programmatically in Program.cs/Startup.cs?

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor-server-side

Is there a way to set the initial url for ASP.NET Core programmatically? Preferably in the `Startup.cs/Program.cs` file?

Essentially, I'm after the same feature as the `launchUrl` property in the `launchsettings.json` file:

```json
{
  "profiles": {
    "Console": {
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000",
      "launchUrl": "/fred",
    },
  }
}
```

What I want to do is add some code that will only run in `DEBUG` mode and alter the `launchUrl` based on a setting I have in my user secrets (avoiding any chance of accidentally adding this ad hoc config to the repo).

Does anyone know if this is possible?

Comment: Yes you can do that by using: `builder.WebHost.UseUrls("http://localhost:5050/");`, it will overridee your `launchUrl` on runtime.

Comment: In addition, you need to check `if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)` then reset the `builder.WebHost.UseUrls` inside this block.

Answer (score 0):

If you are developing in visual studio then it have defined preprocessor in build configuration So you can just embed the lines in program.cs for .Net 6

```
#if DEBUG
builder.WebHost.UseUrls("http://localhost:5050", "https://localhost:5051"); // just put your urls from secret here
#endif
```

For other versions just find out where webhost is built. There will be some familiar codes like code below or so on.

```
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
```

Comment: Hi, I believe what you're talking about is the `applicationUrl` - which is the list of urls that the app is bound to. `launchUrl` is the initial url/route that's displayed when the app starts. So instead of starting in the root route `/` I'd like to set it to something like `/fred`